# Azure DevOps - Moving TVCS Repo from one tenant to another - 2021

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Before posting this question I have looked through all the similar ones. Finding no workable solution I am asking for help.

Thanks in advance!

I am trying to copy the repository from one tenant to another one using the following approach:

1. (done) Download the tool: Download Microsoft Git-TF for Visual Studio Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Online from Official Microsoft Download Center
2. (done) Download Git-TF and Git-TFS (done with using git-tfs)
3. Clone an existing TFVC repo to my local machine as a Git repo using the Git-Tf tool: git-tf clone https://dev.azure.com/myorg/ "$/mysourceteamproject/mysourcebranch" --deep git-tf is no longer supported so I used git-tfs here. git-tfs clone https://dev.azure.com/myorg/ "$/mysourceteamproject/mysourcebranch" --deep
4. (done) Cd into the directory that the code was cloned into and push the local Git repo to any empty remote Git repo (this will be used as a temporary repo during the migration) git remote add origin https://user@dev.azure.com/myorg/anyteamproject/_git/tempgitrepo git push -u origin –all
5. (done with using git-tfs) Cloned the temporary Git repo to my local machine git-tfs clone https://user@dev.azure.com/myorg/anyteamproject/_git/tempgitrepo
6. (done ) Created an empty new folder “migrated” in the existing target TFVC repo (done with git-ft but from this step I am not sure it is a correct approach now) Cd into the directory that the code was cloned into, and run the configure command: git-tf configure https://dev.azure.com/myorg/ "$/mytargetteamproject/migrated" (here git-tf does not due to Basic Authentication issue as it is no longer supported. Using gif-tfs led to bootstrapping to the tenant we would like to copy from - to original )
7. Run the pull command to merge two repos does not work - git-tf pull leads to bootstrapping to the wrong tenant - git-tfs pull the steps below simply cannot be executed as the step 8 cannot be completed properly.
8. Run a basic git commit command git commit -a -m "merge commit"
9. Checkin to the TFVC repo git-tf checkin –deep --metadata

The question is - is there a way to move TVCS repo from one tenant to another TVCS tenant repo?

Comment: Don't use `git-tf`. It's no longer supported and is strictly inferior to a different tool with a similar name, `git-tfs`.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I managed - of cause not only me - to do migration.
Unfortunately, git-tfs could not be used as it works not as git-tf.

**The main issue was Authorization step with using git-tf.
Using token name and token as user name and password accordingly helped a lot.**

All the steps done can be seen below:

1. **Install GIT, GIT-TF, Java**
2. To clone source repository to local GIT

   ```
   git-tf clone https://azerov:[source token]@dev.azure.com/OrganizationName "$/D365FOps_Learn02/Trunk" --deep
   username: TestPatMigration (the name of the token)
   password: [source token]
   ```
3. Create any remote GIT repository to push local cloned repo there
4. cd into cloned repo c:\users[curuser]\Trunk

   ```
   git remote add origin 
   https://azerov:[git temporary target token]@dev.azure.com/OrganizationNameTarget/GitTemp02/_git/GitTemp02**
   ```
5. To push local cloned repo into temporary GIT repo

   ```
   git push -u origin –-all
   ```
6. To clone temporary git repo to local machine

   ```
   git clone https://azerov:[git temporary target token]@dev.azure.com/OrganizationNameTarget/GitTemp02/_git/GitTemp02
   ```
7. To configure the target TFVS Project to push local temporary GIT repo there

   ```
   cd into c:\users\GitTemp2
   git-tf configure https://azerov:[git temporary target token]@dev.azure.com/OrganizationNameTarget/ “$/D365FOps_learn02/Trunk”
   ```
8. ```
   git-tf pull

   Username:  PATMigration (the name of the target source token)
   password: [git temporary target token]
   ```
9. ```
   git commit -a -m "merge commit"
   ```
10. ```
    git-tf checkin –-deep –-metadata
    ```